# Reorder html elements in a string using C#

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have a string of html returning from a serivce. I need to update this html server side (Using .Net) and reorder some of the elements around before sending it to the client. As a simple example lets say I have an html string like below. If the string is  a table like below. How can I manipulate it to put the last name `<th>` and `<td>` into it's own `<tr>`. The html would be much larger and more complex but for one section of it the below illustrate how I would need to change it. Just using string replace hasn't worked well due to the complexity of the actual HTML.

**Initial String**

```
   "<table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <td>some first name</td>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <td>some last name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>blah</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    "
```

**After Modification**

```
   "<table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <td>some first name</td>
      </tr>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <td>some last name</td>
      <tr>
        <th>blah</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    "
```

Comment: Where is your effort. " What's the best approach for manipulating" - primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do from your question. Please post the order "before" and the order "after" the changes you want to make.

Comment: Can you get around the webservice returning HTML? If it's just a table, this could be better represented in a JSON object of string arrays. For that particular case,if you want it to be absolutley clean, you can even write an XSLT transformation (view the HTML as XML, http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) and apply it to the XML doc. Otherwise, you should better specify  what kind of "manipulations" you want to do, i.e. give some expected outputs.

Comment: Sorry for how the inital question was put together. I have updated it.

Comment: Your after HTML looks like it is missing an additional `<tr>` and `</tr>` around the Last name cols,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, I will make the silly assumption that you have read the file in a string list. Let us name this list HTMLLines. Then the following should do what you want

```
int length=HTMLLines.Count;
for(int loop=0;loop<length;loop++)
{
     if(HTMLLines[loop].Equals("<th>Last name</th>"))
     {
          HTMLLines[loop]="</tr>\n<tr>\n"+HTMLLines[loop];
          //break;//If there is only one occurrence, remove the leading // else keep that to repeat for each occurence
     }
}
```

If you save the list after this loop, you should have the desired output.

This code assumes that there are no nulls in the list. If there are any nulls, you should replace `HTMLLines[loop].Equals("<th>Last name</th>")` with `HTMLLines[loop]=="<th>Last name</th>"`

If the `"<th>Last name</th>"` is just a sample you used for this question that cannot be used to match exactly, then you should place all possible matches to an array and check for them each loop. In this case, if we name the array `theHeaders`, the code will be something like:

```
int length=HTMLLines.Count;
for(int loop=0;loop<length;loop++)
{
     for(int loop1=0;loop1<theHeaders.Length;loop1++)
     {
         if(HTMLLines[loop].Equals(theHeaders[loop1]))
         {
              HTMLLines[loop]="</tr>\n<tr>\n"+HTMLLines[loop];
              break;
         }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps to point you to the right direction.

Comment: super helpful especially the last part

Answer (score 1):

I know URL answers are frowned upon, but you should look into the HTML Agility Pack. It's designed for this kind of thing.

http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach could be...

```
var result = htmlString.Replace("<th>Last name</th>", "</tr><tr><th>Last name</th>");
```

If you need something more complex than this you'll need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately this would be too simple of an approach for my case. I have added some additional detail to the question.

Comment: My solution still works for your updated details. You need to provide all expected cases of your data. Are you trying to replace any case with 4 cols to 2? Or all cases of last name? Or generally fix any mismatch in table columns which is much harder.

Comment: The content in the tags is dynamic that's why I dont think this would work

Comment: Can you give different examples where it won't work?  It's currently hard to tell what we should be expecting in the HTML.